# How to use bin edges at the x-axis of a histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, toplevel

I'm rather new with regard to Matplotlib which want to use for making (multiple) histograms of data counts with float intervals on the x-axis in a tkinter toplevel window. See below a highly simplified part of my code. Because I use float intervals, I need to apply a ax2.hist(...) call in stead of the ax1.bar(...) call. See my code below. However, the result from ax2.hist(...) is not what I want. I would like tot have the counts at the y-axis as is the case in ax1. With other words, how do I get a histogram with y-axis from ax1 and the x-axis from ax2?
I hope somebody can suggest how to deal with this. I couldn't find it on the matplotlib site, sofar.

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np
import random

root = tk.Tk()
panel = tk.Toplevel()
panel.title('Title')

lijst = []
for i in range(100):
    a = random.randrange(100)
    a=a/10
    lijst.append(a)
nplijst = np.array(lijst)
counts, bins = np.histogram(nplijst)

names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' ,'i', 'j']
print(counts)
print(bins)[![resulting ax1 bar graph and ax2 histogram][1]][1]
fig1 = plt.Figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(122)
ax1.bar(names, counts, width = 1, edgecolor="k")
ax2.hist(counts, bins = bins, edgecolor="k")
ax1.set_title('ax1')
ax2.set_title('ax2')

chart_type1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, panel)
chart_type1.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sharey` keyword in `plt.subplots` like so:

```
fig1, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)  # create a 1x2 grid of plots
axs[0].bar(names, counts, width = 1, edgecolor="k")
axs[1].hist(counts, bins = bins, edgecolor="k")
axs[0].set_title('ax1')
axs[1].set_title('ax2')
```

If you want the tick labels back on the second plot, add

```
for ax in axs:
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelleft=True)
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thank you. However, I noticed that I had formulated my question not clear enough. I just wanted to have similar graph as ax1 but with the x-axis of ax2. However in the mean time I found the solution. My error was that I didn't realize that I used already binned data. By changing the call for ax2, i.e.: ax2.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts, edgecolor="k") I got what I wanted. See also https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html